# The method 'registerMessageHandler' isn't defined for the type 'Registrar'

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore_web/cloud_firestore_web.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics_web/firebase_analytics_web.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast_web.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in_web/google_sign_in_web.dart';
import 'package:pak_farmer/models/Register.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences_web/shared_preferences_web.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';

// ignore: public_member_api_docs

void registerPlugins(Registrar registrar) {

  FirebaseFirestoreWeb.registerWith (registrar);
  FirebaseAnalyticsWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseAuthWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseCoreWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FluttertoastWebPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  GoogleSignInPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  registrar**.registerMessageHandler();**
  
}
```

I've written this code but it is giving me an error on the last line:

The method 'registerMessageHandler' isn't defined for the type 'Registrar'.

Answer (score 3):

my error gone with flutter clean once and it will work fine for me

Answer (score 2):

`flutter clean` didn't work for me. My problem was that I made the project in the Flutter beta channel and then opened in the stable channel. When I switched back to beta it was OK. Once web support enters stable this shouldn't be a problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I downgraded Flutter from `2.0.0+` to `1.22.6`. Developed the web panel in `2.0.0+` but after downgrading it for another app, saw this.

The error is likely if you created the project in stable version and for some reason you downgraded to a lower Flutter version.

**FIX:** Upgrade to the higher / updated version **OR** check the channel it was built on and shift to that channel.

You can see which channel you are currently on with `flutter channel` in your cmd.

Answer (score -1):

Delete that autoGenerated file and run the application.

Comment: which autoGenerated file are you talking about? Explain your answer.

Comment: above file is not user generated file it is generated by itself, so if you delete this dart file and run your apk this error will solve.